# Github API - Search by username and user followers in one call

Tags: javascript, api, github

I'm creating a simple github user search app. The intended result of a username search is a list of users each with a corresponding list of their followers.

I have been successful in searching for users, and searching for user followers. Each search as a separate api call.

My question is: Is there a way to get a combined result of users + their respective followers in one api call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [API docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/) the `users/:user` endpoint responds with an object that has a `followers_url` key, which is another endpoint for the user's followers.

So I don't think you can achieve what you're attempting.